# React-router URL endpoints returns NOT FOUND in production environment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-router, react-router-dom

My project is working fine in the local server environment, but since I deployed it on render.com's web server, I'm getting an empty not found page whenever I try to refresh or visit a URL with an endpoint other than the homepage. I read about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top) and tried to implement the catch-all solution but it's not working for me.
My project is made up of two folders a client and a server. I'm using the server as my entry point for the web server I'm hosting on, but I'm not sure if it's unable to send a file from the client folder.

I tried adding the following piece of code to my server.js file.

```
const clientPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'client', 'build')

// Serve static files from the build directory
app.use(express.static(clientPath))

// Catch-all route handler
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  console.log('in catch-all')
  res.sendFile(path.join(clientPath, 'index.html'))
})
```

the catch-all is at the end of the file after all the configured API endpoints in case it's not matching any of the above. The console.log('in catch-all') is not printed on the server's logs when I try visiting a random endpoint.

Comment: Check the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#render) for Render and follow the instructions there to see where any setup/configuration discrepancies may be.

Comment: Found it at https://render.com/docs/deploy-create-react-app. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the case that you are using apache, you can add a .htaccess file, like so:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

Else, you can copy your index.html file and rename it as 200.html. Hope it helps.

Comment: OP says they are using Render.com, so I don't think apache settings/files are applicable here.